# Rails array help - How to order an array after date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to sort an array after dato(date).

I have tried this without luck:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(:name => 'Orville', :order => 'dato ASC').all.map(&:earn) %>
```

And this:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(:name => 'Orville').all.map(&:earn).order('dato ASC') %>
```

And:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(:name => 'Orville').order('dato ASC').all.map(&:earn) %>
```

And:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(:name => 'Orville').all.order('dato ASC').map(&:earn) %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'sort an array after date'? Are you trying to sort by date? What do you want your result to be? What role does the 'earn' attribute play?

Comment: I have found my answer <%= Reklamer.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => 'Orville'}, :select => 'sum(earn) AS earn', :group => 'dato').map(&:earn) %>

Comment: Edit: <%= Reklamer.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => 'Orville'}, :order => 'dato ASC', :select => 'sum(earn) AS earn', :group => 'dato').map(&:earn) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(:name => 'Orville').order('dato ASC').map(&:earn).join(', ') %>
```

Though in general, I would recommend not putting all that data loading code into your view. Instead, push it to your models and controllers. For example, you could do this in your controller:

```
def show
  @earnings = Reklamer.where(:name => 'Orville').order('dato ASC').map(&:earn)
end
```

Or, even better, push some of the more complicated stuff to your model:

```
class Reklamer
  def self.earnings
    where(:name => 'Orville').order('dato ASC').map(&:earn)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have found my answer <%= Reklamer.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => 'Orville'}, :select => 'sum(earn) AS earn', :group => 'dato').map(&:earn) %>

Comment: Is there a good way to set the code in the model? I got some different names, that I just use the code on one page. Wouldn't  it be messy instead?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using Rails 2. Is that correct? If so, I'd recommend upgrading to Rails 3 if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

<%= Reklamer.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => 'Orville'}, :order => 'dato ASC', :select => 'sum(earn) AS earn', :group => 'dato').map(&:earn) %>

Comment: Your call to Reklamer.find is Rails 2 style. I'd recommend you start using the Rails 3 API, which you were actually using in the examples from your original post: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html